# How to create partition on single partitioned disk

Tags: partitioning

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 lts
I have 500 gb single partitioned hard disk on which this ubuntu is installed

now i want to create two partition 
but when I try using gparted it is only showing unmount option(all other options are grey)
so how can i do it without losing any data

Comment: If you used LVM, then it will be "easy" (if you understand LVM). If you did not use LVM, it's dangerous because most "partioners" do not know anything about the data on your disk and they will just cut it in half as required to create your partitions. At least that's how it was before. Maybe `gparted` does a good job on that...

Comment: is local volume manager is more effective than gparted in his job???

Comment: LVM knows how to handle existing data so it won't lose data (although it is somewhat complicated to use, but I think there is a GUI for it.) Either way, if you have data you do not want to lose, as mentioned by Rmano, you should back it up.

Comment: LMV is not there on ubuntu software Center

Comment: You normally decide to use LVM when you install your system. Retrofitting it is quite complex. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm and https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html (scroll down to find LVM). It is quite advanced material; it is not just a program you install.

Answer (score 3):

You can't repartition a partition which is in use. So

1) **backup your data** (1);

2) repartition your disk with `gparted` starting the system with a LiveUSB or LiveDVD (there is a gparted LiveCD somewhere around).

(1) In theory the resizing of a modern ext4 partition should be safe and without data loss. But when doing such kind of highly potentially disruptive operations, a backup is fundamental.(2)

(2) well... I have daily backup even when I do almost nothing. YMMV...

Comment: is there any data loss or ubuntu os corruption during the whole process???

Comment: there may be 1 percent chance of data loss.

Comment: there is gparted software livecd available...so is it able to do the job??

Comment: yes both the gparted live cd and ubuntu live cd will does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize your single HDD partition only through Gparted live disk or Ubuntu live disk.

Comment: hey i have downloaded gparted live disk through mozilla...but it has been saved in root folder by default..now that root folder is inaccessible..so how can i access this??

Comment: post the output of `sudo ls /root`.

Comment: Desktop gparted-live-0.17.0-4-i486.iso

Comment: saying that command not found..

Comment: `sudo cp /root/gparted-live-0.17.0-4-i486.iso ~/Desktop`

Comment: post the error after running the above command.

Comment: or try these two commands `sudo -i` and `cp gparted-live-0.17.0-4-i486.iso ~/Desktop`

Comment: ya now it worked...thnks

Comment: of course but after successful partition..

Comment: now its there but i am unable to burn it nor able to copy it to usb drive...it's saying permission denied

Comment: even now root is the owner of that file..so its showing permission denied

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu or, better... http://lmgtfy.com/?q=How+to+create+a+bootable+USB+%20on+Ubuntu# ;-)

Comment: try this command `sudo chmod 777 ~/Desktop/gparted-live-0.17.0-4-i486.iso`.Now you can be able to copy.